# Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'html' has already been declared

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why it is giving me this error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'html' has already been declared (at obtenerTipos.js:1:1) at obtenerTipos.js:1:

```
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttp.open(
  "GET",
  "http://localhost:8080/recetarioappmain/sistema/API/tipos.php",
  false
); // false for synchronous request
xmlHttp.send(null);
//console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);

//Convertimos en objeto
var resultadoTipos = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);

//console.log(resultadoTipos);

var html = '<option value="">Seleccione un tipo</option>';
for (var i = 0; i < resultadoTipos.length; i++) {
  html +=
    '<option value="' +
    resultadoTipos[i].id +
    '">' +
    resultadoTipos[i].nombre +
    "</option>";
}

document.getElementById("id_tipos").innerHTML += html;
```

Can anybody help me? I can't see what's going on.

Thank you

Comment: Looks like somewhere else (in code that you don't show here) the `html` variable has already been declared. (Presumably with `let html` or `const html`.)

Comment: @ivar It tells me that it has already been declared in obtenerTipos.js and this is the code that is there.

Comment: Are you maybe accidentally loading in this script twice instead of once? (I.e. `<script src="obtenerTipos.js"></script>` tags in two places.)

Comment: I'd recommend running this in an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression) to avoid conflicts with any globally declared variables.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try rename your variable and replace all instances to verify Ivar's explanation

```
// var html = '<option value="">Seleccione un tipo</option>';
var my_unique_html = '<option value="">Seleccione un tipo</option>';
```

Comment: Changing the name worked for me and I took advantage of to change var to let. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. Could you upvote this answer as its marked as correct.

Answer (score 0):

When using `let` or `const` you can only declare a variable once within a given scope, and trying to do it again will throw this type of error. `var` doesn't throw an error when you try to redeclare the same variable because it works slightly differently than `let`. So to answer your question, somewhere in your code you've already declared html with `let` or `const` that matches the same scope `var` is trying to redeclare in.

In general, you shouldn't use var anymore these days as the scope of a variable declared with `var` is scoped either globally or to the function. Meaning the variable `a` here is valid when the console tries to log it while `b` will throw an error as it doesn't exist outside the block of the if statement.

```js
if (someCondition) {
    var a = 'someValue'
    let b = 'someOtherValue'
}
console.log(a)
console.log(b)
```

This can cause problems in your code as you might be overwriting variables when you didn't mean to. `let` and `const` are both scoped to the block they're declared in.

You can read more about `var` here: https://javascript.info/var

Answer (score -1):

Have u tried to change the html to another name?